# Unable to validate Antiforgery token when cookie is set to httponly

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken, cookie-httponly

When i set the value of httponly=true. AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute doesnot validate the request and return 400 bad request

```
AntiforgeryTokenSet tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
   context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken,
    new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true});
```

After doing this cookie become secure as shown below

`set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN={{Cookie Value}}; path=/; samesite=lax; httponly`

But AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute returns 400 bad request

`when changed the Value HttpOnly = true to HttpOnly = false`

It works perfectly fine. Is there is way to set antiforgerytoken cookie to httponly in asp core and angular 7. If it will not work can some body please guide me through about the reason behind it.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible for this particular cookie to be set to http-only. To understand *why*, have a look at the following section from the ASP.NET Core [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#angularjs):

> AngularJS uses a convention to address CSRF. If the server sends a cookie with the name `XSRF-TOKEN`, the AngularJS `$http` service adds the cookie value to a header when it sends a request to the server.

This talks about AngularJS and `$http`, but the same mechanism is used for Angular and its `HttpClient` service (see the Angular [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#security-xsrf-protection)).

To be able to add the cookie value to a header, Angular must be able to *read* the value out of the cookie. When you set the cookie to `HttpOnly`, Angular is unable to read the value from the cookie (it's as if it doesn't even exist). Thus the value is not sent and the server rejects the request.